# TypeError: API.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait_on_rate_limit_notify'

Tags: python, api, tweepy

```
import tweepy
import time
import random
print('Bot Starting...')
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_KEY = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True)
```

I keep getting this error; I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [documentation of the latest version](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html), there is no such argument, hence the error.

The [changelog](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/changelog.html?highlight=notify) indicates the parameter was removed and now:

> Always log warning when rate limit reached.

Answer (score 0):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) removed this parameter and always logs a warning by default now.
You can simply stop passing it.